# Google App Engine - Node.js entrypoint as defined in the app.yaml isn't triggering

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-app-engine, next.js, app.yaml

I have a node.js application that's been Dockerized with `gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs` and deploys and runs fine. Knowing that by default GAE will run the "start" script in the package.json I simply replaced what was already there with `next start -p 8080` which runs no problem.

I'd like to trigger an alternative script rather than "start" and so I created a script called "cloud-start" and plugged in the above command as the value. In the app.yaml I added the "entrypoint" property and `yarn cloud-run` as the value:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: yarn cloud-start
service: my-app

vm_health_check:
 enable_health_check: False

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  memory_gb: 4
```

The "cloud-start" script is never executed though - I even tried replacing "yarn" with "npm" and still no luck. Why would my entrypoint not be triggering?

Here's my Dockerfile just in case its relevant:

```
# Use the base App Engine Docker image, based on Ubuntu 16.0.4.
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs

# Install locate for debugging purposes
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q \
    locate

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN  npm install --global yarn
RUN yarn
RUN yarn static

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the package.json file too? Also include the error messages as well from the app engine logs.

Answer (score 4):

Try `entrypoint: npm run cloud-start` it works for me.

Explanation of this answer can be found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110097743#comment11

> `yarn` is only available at build time to install your dependencies. The yarn executable is not available in the Node.js runtime after that.

> If you want to run your "dev" script, just use "start" : "npm run dev"